# В чем разница подключения стилей?

Tags: html, css

Знаю, что стили подключаются путем относительно страницы, но работая над одним проектам заметил такую интересную вещь

```
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="/css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Слэши наоборот - прямые и сам путь к странице не относительный

- путь к странице, к которой подключаю
  `project\resources\views\catalog\homepage.html`
- путь css, который    подключается(?)
  `project\public\css\shop-homepage.css`

---

А главное, что когда вношу изменения в css, они не отражаются на странице. Возник логичный вопрос: что это и с чем его едят?

Comment: это винда так делает - слеш должен быть / вот такой

Comment: @MaximLensky, для windows все равно в какую сторону наклонены слэши

Comment: но почему путь не относительный?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

слэши всегда используются прямые (вне зависимости от серверной оси). Надеюсь вы обновляете страницу полностью? Потому как css кэшируется по-умолчанию и то что вы изменили видно и не будет, пока не обновите кэш.